Error: Microsoft.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform when publishing .NET 8.0 C# Web API to IIS
I'm working on a C# Web API project with the following setup:
csproj is
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="Controllers\ProductController.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="8.0.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="8.0.10">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="8.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.9.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>

The API works perfectly in my development environment, but after publishing it to IIS, I encounter the following error:

"error": "Microsoft.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform."

What I’ve Tried:

Ensured the .NET 8 Hosting Bundle is installed on the server.
Checked platform compatibility and set the application pool accordingly.
Verified Microsoft.Data.SqlClient and other NuGet package versions.
Configured the IIS Application Pool to use "No Managed Code."
Attempted a self-contained deployment.

Despite these steps, the issue persists. Any insights or suggestions to resolve this would be greatly appreciated!

I suggest you could first re-check your publish setting, you should make sure you have set the publish setting well.

Secondly, I suggest you could recheck the Microsoft.Data.SqlClient package version to use different version  to test like 5.1.5 , 5.2.0, 5.2.2.
Besides,  if above steps now working, you could follow this github issue.

Thank you, Brando! I updated the folder publishing profile as shown in the screenshot, and it worked like a charm. I really appreciate your guidance.
